# libgflags invalid, checking gflags viability failed

Tags: redhat, gflags

I try to install folly on redhat 7.2,and i have downloaded  gflags source code from github,compile and install. Howerver, Folly installation still faile. Anyone have some ideal? appreciated for your help.
ERROR MESSAGE shown below:
checking for main in -lgflags... yes
checking for gflags viability... no
configure: error: "libgflags invalid, see config.log for details"